# What is the best blog engine that runs on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the best blog engine that runs on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Google Apps -> Google Sites. It lets you easily configure a blog.

For GAE, there are some engines out there, but none of the in the league of Google Sites or Wordpress:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086465/blog-engine-for-google-app-engine

Comment: The question you linked to has been deleted